# No view found for id - DialogFragment + Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, fragmenttransaction, android-nested-fragment

I have a DialogFragment with a simple layout. I want to add a fragment (and in the future replace this fragment with another) to a FrameLayout that is inside the DialogFragment's layout. However, the method of adding the new fragment fails with the error:

"No view found for id 0x7f0b004f com.kennel39.diabeteslive_adtdev:id/frameAlertsContainer) for       fragment Fragment_AlertsManage {41e7cb68}"

I have checked my xml, attempted different methods and have read a number of similar issues on stackoverflow but I cannot find a solution.

```
public class DialogManageAlerts extends DialogFragment{
static int patient_id;

public static DialogManageAlerts newInstance(int given_patient_id){
    DialogManageAlerts frag = new DialogManageAlerts();
    patient_id = given_patient_id;

    Bundle bund = new Bundle();
    bund.putInt("Patient_id", patient_id);
    frag.setArguments(bund);
    return frag;
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_alerts_master, container, false);              
    getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction myTransact = myFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    Fragment_AlertsManage manageAlertsFragment = new Fragment_AlertsManage();
    myTransact.add(R.id.frameAlertsContainer, manageAlertsFragment);
    myTransact.commit();

    return mainView;
}
```

layout.dialog_alerts_master:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white_regular" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/lower_border_background_white">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvManageAlertsTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/manage_alerts_title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameAlertsContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </FrameLayout>    
</LinearLayout>
```

And the Fragment_AlertsManage class:

```
public class Fragment_AlertsManage extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
    int patient_id;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alerts_manage, container, false); 

        //Get buttons       
        Button btnAdd = (Button)myView.findViewById(R.id.btnAddAlert);
        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button btnBack = (Button)myView.findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
        btnBack.setOnClickListener(this);

        //FILL CONTENT
        populateContent(myView);

        return myView;      
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnAddAlert: {
                //Switch fragment
                FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction myTransact = myFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                Fragment_AlertsAdd addAlertFragment = new Fragment_AlertsAdd();
                myTransact.addToBackStack("Previous");
                myTransact.replace(this.getView().getId(), addAlertFragment);
                myTransact.commit();

                break;
            }
            case R.id.btnBack: {
                FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction myTransact = myFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                myTransact.remove(Fragment_AlertsManage.this);
                //Launch Home
                Intent homeIntent = new Intent(this.getActivity(), HomeActivity.class);
                homeIntent.putExtra("patient_id", patient_id);
                startActivity(homeIntent);
                getActivity().finish();

                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void populateContent(View myView){
        try {
            ArrayList<Alert> alerts = new RetrieveAlerts(patient_id).execute().get();

            ListView list = (ListView) myView.findViewById(R.id.reminder_listview);
            AlertsListAdapter alertsAdapter = new AlertsListAdapter(this.getActivity(), alerts);
            list.setAdapter(alertsAdapter);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Why am I getting this error, and what can I do to solve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The doc on `getFragmentManager()`:

> Return the FragmentManager for interacting with fragments associated
>   with this fragment's activity.

R.id.frameAlertsContainer is in the DialogFragment's layout, not the activity's layout, so it can't find it. Try using getChildFragmentManager() instead. However I can't tell if this will work inside the onCreateView() method since the view isn't associated with the fragment yet. You may need to put it in onStart() or something else.

Comment: Problem solved, and it works inside onCreateView so no changes required there for me. Thanks

Comment: ```getChildFragmentManager()``` fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, for resolved, i can the getFragmentManager() in method OnStart() and work perfect.